# Wavy effect for my svg Bezier curve Does it possible?

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to add wavy effect to my line

```html
<svg width="1440" height="768" viewBox="0 0 1440 768" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M-83.6143 -168.119C-83.6143 -168.119 -28.2399 30.8053 74.4593 88.0896C221.086 169.876 364.03 -134.373 489.568 -22.8989C541.227 22.9737 522.397 86.2632 573.454 132.805C668.648 219.579 808.738 68.6733 902.337 157.164C984.353 234.705 886.122 360.221 967.307 438.631C1076.34 543.937 1234.26 326.531 1354.83 418.414C1480.33 514.051 1274.03 778.862 1427.47 815.613C1487.58 830.013 1584.35 794.881 1584.35 794.881" stroke="#979F79" stroke-width="2">
 </path>
</svg>
```

But idk what way is right.
Guess, i need to change start and end points from js.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `M-83.6143 -168.119` start point, `1584.35 794.881` end point. (I hope this helps a bit)

Comment: Evolutionxbox  is right. Try using this instead: `viewBox="-83 -168 1668 987"`

Comment: @enxaneta I wanna get something like wavify, but Idk how its working

Comment: @evolutionxbox I wanna get something like wavify, but Idk how its working

Comment: Can you provide an expected output, e.g. in the form of simple animated gif?

Comment: @JanStránský https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/BPrNPg Like that. But without fill only stroke 2px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To ensure that the SVG curve does not go beyond the SVG canvas, it is necessary to accurately calculate its overall dimensions.
It can be done with JS [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) method.

```js
let bb = wave.getBBox();

console.log(bb);
```

```html
<svg width="1440" height="768" viewBox="0 0 1440 768" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path id="wave" d="M-83.6143 -168.119C-83.6143 -168.119 -28.2399 30.8053 74.4593 88.0896C221.086 169.876 364.03 -134.373 489.568 -22.8989C541.227 22.9737 522.397 86.2632 573.454 132.805C668.648 219.579 808.738 68.6733 902.337 157.164C984.353 234.705 886.122 360.221 967.307 438.631C1076.34 543.937 1234.26 326.531 1354.83 418.414C1480.33 514.051 1274.03 778.862 1427.47 815.613C1487.58 830.013 1584.35 794.881 1584.35 794.881" stroke="#979F79" stroke-width="2">
  </path>
 </svg>
```

Add the resulting numbers to the `viewBox`

Was `viewBox ="0 0 1440 768"` Now `viewBox ="- 83 -168 1668 987"

```html
<svg width="1440" height="768" viewBox="-83 -168 1668 987" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<path id="wave" d="M-83.6143 -168.119C-83.6143 -168.119 -28.2399 30.8053 74.4593 88.0896C221.086 169.876 364.03 -134.373 489.568 -22.8989C541.227 22.9737 522.397 86.2632 573.454 132.805C668.648 219.579 808.738 68.6733 902.337 157.164C984.353 234.705 886.122 360.221 967.307 438.631C1076.34 543.937 1234.26 326.531 1354.83 418.414C1480.33 514.051 1274.03 778.862 1427.47 815.613C1487.58 830.013 1584.35 794.881 1584.35 794.881" stroke="#979F79" stroke-width="2">

    </path>
</svg>
```

### Technique of getting animation of `d` `path` attribute step by step

1. Load your svg file into a vector editor such as Inkscape
2. Select the path and clone it

[image]

### Note

That the animation runs smoothly without jumps, it is necessary that the number of node points and their type are the same in the start and end positions.

Curve cloning is the easiest trick to meet this condition.

[image]

3. To change the curve clone, change the position of the node points (in the figure, the red curve)
4. Save the file in a vector editor
5. Copy the patches of the start and end positions of the curve
6. The animation of the `d` attribute is to move from the start position to the end

`values="path-start;path-finish"`

**Update**

If you want a repeating animation from the start position to the final position and back to the start position

`values="path-start;path-finish;path-start"`

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="1440" height="768" viewBox="-83 -168 1668 987" fill="none" version="1.1" border="1">
  <path d="M-83.6-168.1C-83.6-168.1-28.2 30.8 74.5 88.1 221.1 169.9 364-134.4 489.6-22.9 541.2 23 522.4 86.3 573.5 132.8 668.6 219.6 808.7 68.7 902.3 157.2 984.4 234.7 886.1 360.2 967.3 438.6 1076.3 543.9 1234.3 326.5 1354.8 418.4 1480.3 514.1 1274 778.9 1427.5 815.6 1487.6 830 1584.4 794.9 1584.4 794.9" stroke="#979F79"  fill="none" stroke-width="2">
    <animate
      attributeName="d"
      dur="5s"
      begin="0s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values ="
        M-83.6-168.1C-83.6-168.1-28.2 30.8 74.5 88.1 221.1 169.9 364-134.4 489.6-22.9 541.2 23 522.4 86.3 573.5 132.8 668.6 219.6 808.7 68.7 902.3 157.2 984.4 234.7 886.1 360.2 967.3 438.6 1076.3 543.9 1234.3 326.5 1354.8 418.4 1480.3 514.1 1274 778.9 1427.5 815.6 1487.6 830 1584.4 794.9 1584.4 794.9;
        
        m-78.8 87.9c0 0 171-311.8 255.7-230.2 124.2 119.8 84.8 203 207.1 230.2 140.8 0 99.3-262.4 265.6-179.1 199.2 49.5 254.4-56.1 316.7-1.2 89.6 31.1-70.6 478.5 36.2 515 149 50.9 195-20.9 315.5 71 125.5 95.6-26.4 245.3 127 282 60.1 14.4 139.3 19.3 139.3 19.3;
        
        M-83.6-168.1C-83.6-168.1-28.2 30.8 74.5 88.1 221.1 169.9 364-134.4 489.6-22.9 541.2 23 522.4 86.3 573.5 132.8 668.6 219.6 808.7 68.7 902.3 157.2 984.4 234.7 886.1 360.2 967.3 438.6 1076.3 543.9 1234.3 326.5 1354.8 418.4 1480.3 514.1 1274 778.9 1427.5 815.6 1487.6 830 1584.4 794.9 1584.4 794.9"
        />
        
  </path>

  <!-- <path d="m-83.6-168.1c0 0 55.4 85.3 158.1 142.6 146.6 81.8 289.6-222.5 415.1-111 51.7 45.9 30.5 67.5 81.6 114 95.2 86.8 239.1-120 332.7-31.5 82 77.5-19.4 337.4 61.8 415.8 109 105.3 270.4-206.5 390.9-114.6 125.5 95.6-83.1 331.7 70.4 368.4 60.1 14.4 157.3 179.2 157.3 179.2" style="fill:none;stroke-width:2;stroke:#f00c79"/> -->
</svg>
```

You can change the shape of the curve in the final position to your liking.
Hope this answer helps you

Comment: What I need to do, if I wanna create wave like this http://skrinshoter.ru/s/300820/GIe0lA0s. I have to take coords from saved svg file, path, d attr or path > animate tag > values?

Comment: @Solarsystem You need to substitute the coordinates into the `values` (m-78.8 87.9c ... 19.3;) attribute of the final curve path, as in my example. You will have different values from your saved file. The rest will be exactly the same as in the example.

Answer (score 3):

### Another example of animating the `d` attribute

Here is another form of path that looks more like a wave

The technique for obtaining the final patch is the same as in the first example.

1. Start path

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

2. End path

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300" preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C157.16,-41.94 281.88,148.52 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;"/>
</svg>
</div>
```

*Wave animation*

```css
* {
padding:0;
margin:0;
}
body {
background:greenyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="morph-shape" id="morph-shape"  >
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="dodgerblue" d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z">
  <animate
    attributeName="d"
    dur="7s"
    repeatCount="indefinite" 
  values=" 
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;
    M0.00,49.98 C157.16,-41.94 281.88,148.52 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z;
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z" />
</path> 
</svg> 
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

> [codepen.io/manabox/pen/BPrNPg](http://codepen.io/manabox/pen/BPrNPg) Like that. But without fill only stroke
> 2px

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1000 300"  preserveAspectRatio="none">
<path fill="none" stroke="dodgerblue" stroke-width="2" d="M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 L500.00,0.00 L0.00,0.00 Z">
  <animate
    attributeName="d"
    dur="7s"
    repeatCount="indefinite" 
  values=" 
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 ;
    M0.00,49.98 C157.16,-41.94 281.88,148.52 500.00,49.98 ;
    M0.00,49.98 C149.99,150.00 271.49,-49.98 500.00,49.98 " />
</path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: Apparently the OP wants it _without fill only stroke 2px_ (last comment)

Comment: @enxaneta Thanks enxaneta I looked at the author's link for an example on the codepen there is a fill. And it looks better with filling.
If the author does not need a fill, then there is no problem to remove it.